# NHibernate, Oracle and Tablespaces

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm able to generate tables in an Oracle database but they are generated on the default tablespace.

Does anyone know how to specify which tablespace they should be created on using NHibernate (or your favourite fluent mapping API)?

If I create the tables manually (**specifying the tablespace on creation**) I can subsequently insert data into them via NHibernate and my C# code.

Generating the tables via NHibernate, and then trying to insert data, I get the following errors:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [Some.Namespace.Core.MyObjectTable#fba3213d-bf7d-11e1-b71d-005056a80403][SQL: INSERT INTO "MyObjectTable" (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
```

With inner exception:

```
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'THE_DEFAULT_TABLESPACE'
```

Surely there is a way around this...? I'm having no such problems with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need a quota on the tablespace. From a dba account you can for instance run the following statement:

```
alter user <myuser> quota 5m on tablespace the_default_tablespace;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dude, but I really want to be able to automatically generate tables in a given tablespace and then insert data into them. Instead at the moment, the code creates tables on the default tablespace which I don't have priviliges on. If I manually create tables via an sql script and then try inserting data via NHibernate, everything works fine. But this defeats the point of an ORM.

Comment: Then Dude you need to specify the tablespace when create the table

Comment: Which was the original question. But let me be more specific (I'll edit the question... slightly). I need to specify the tablespace in NHibernate, but all attempts so far have been fruitless.